# Certificate error when loading an url to an image source

Tags: image, actionscript-3, apache-flex, url, certificate

I got an image, and I assign the source property like this:

image.source = "https://www.company.com/imageName.jpg";

This works ok in some PC's, but in others I got an error, I debuggde the error with Fiddler Web Debugger and it says something like this:

"The remote server presented a certificate that did not validate due to RemoteCertificateNameMismatch, RemoteCertificateChainErrors".

Do you know what could it be?, and why it works from some computers but not from others?.

Comment: Are you sure you can access the image from those machines that give you this error.  At the office, our hardware based firewall blocks many things, and then gives you a certificate error (obviously self-signing or something).  Make sure the IE connection settings are the same on the machines in question and that transports are consistent (firewall, proxy, etc.)

Comment: It is actually a swf file inside a pdf file (a portfolio), I'm not using a web browser. And yeah, the images can be reached from those machines.

Comment: Curious.  Out of ideas though.  Sorry I cannot be more help.

Comment: Btw I've found this link: http://www.onegiantmedia.com/as3--load-a-remote-image-from-any-url--domain-with-no-stupid-security-sandbox-errors

I noticed I'm not using any security policy, should I?.

Comment: Sorry - my skills on SWF (and related) = -500 reputation. :)

Answer (score 1):

The image is located on a secure website, I believe this because you used https in your example. The error is about that certificate provided by the website you're trying to get the image from. Clearly it's not a trusted certificate.
Are you using the same pdf reader software on all the pc's? Some pdf reader might be more strict then others in regards to certificates.

Answer (score 1):

You did not specify what PC are working fine so it will be hard to answer correctly. It might be important to know what OS is installed on the PCs (working and not working), what version of PDF reader is installed and if all PCs are in same network environment.

I have no experience with actionscript or swf, but the questions I would be asking are:

1. who does certificate validation in this case? Is it windows or PDF reader?
2. And where are certificates of trusted root authorities kept? Does all the PCs have this in common?

I believe that if you find answers to these questions, you will solve your problem easily.